# Why electric potential at the centre of a uniformly charged insulating sphere is more than the electric potential at the surface of the sphere?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, work

Since value of electric field decreases as we go from surface to the centre for a solid insulating uniformly charged sphere then why does the potential increases as we go from surface to the centre?According to me we will need to do less work against weak electric field therefore the potential will be less as we go inside the sphere from the surface since electric field is decreasing as we go from the surface to the centre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the absolute value of the electric potential does not have a physical meaning: only potential differences between two points have meaning.
Mathematically speaking the radial component of the electric field $E$ at a given distance $r$ from the center is the negative derivative of the potential $V(r)$:
$$
E(r) = - \frac{dV}{dr},
$$
which means that only the slope of the function $V(r)$ has a physical meaning. In fact, inside the sphere the electric field is $E(r) = \alpha r$, where $\alpha$ is a constant, which means $V(r) = \text{const} - \frac{1}{2}\alpha r^2 $ and the radial profile of $V(r)$ is a concave down parabola.
This implies that the potential difference between two points A and B taken at a given fixed distance $AB$ is smaller when the points are taken close to $r=0$ than when they are taken far away from $r=0$, and this is totally consistent with your argument about the work of electric forces.

Comment: can you please explain, how you have derived. V(r)=const-1/2×alpha×r²

Comment: are you familiar with derivatives? in that case, just derive it with respect to $r$ and you get $E(r)$

Comment: ok got it...thanks